# OpenEJB : Configuring MDBs with custom ConnectionFactory

Tags: ejb, openejb

As described in OpenEJB docs, we can configure JMS connection factory and queues, and they will appear in JNDI as:

```
openejb:Resource/MyJmsConnectionFactory, 
openejb:Resource/MyQueue
```

1. Given those JNDI entries, how can I tell to MDB to use them?
2. Is it possible to change JNDI name, for example ConnectionFactory to appear as `java:/ConnectionFactory`
   or `ConnectionFactory`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things work differently than you may be imagining.  Specifying that an MDB is tied to a javax.jms.Queue and the name of that queue is part of the EJB specification and done via the ActivationConfig, like so:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(
           propertyName = "destinationType", 
           propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(
           propertyName = "destination", 
           propertyValue = "FooQueue")})
public static class JmsBean implements MessageListener {

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
    }
}
```

The MDB container itself is not actually JMS-aware at all.  It simply understands that it should hook the bean up to a specific Resource Adapter.

```
<openejb>
    <Resource id="MyJmsResourceAdapter" type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
        ServerUrl tcp://someHostName:61616
    </Resource>

    <Container id="MyJmsMdbContainer" ctype="MESSAGE">
        ResourceAdapter MyJmsResourceAdapter
    </Container>
</openejb>
```

The above shows an MDB Container hooked up to a Resource Adapter that uses JMS via ActiveMQ.

Here is an example that shows an MDB Container hooked up to a [Quartz Resource Adapter](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/openejb/tags/openejb-3.1.3/examples/quartz-app/)

It isn't possible to tell the MDB Container about JMS specific things as per specification, the relationship is much more generic than that.  This [blog post](http://blog.dblevins.com/2010/10/ejbnext-connectorbean-api-jax-rs-and.html) gives some insight as to how things work.